# Access private template with friend declaration

Tags: c++, templates, friend

Class B uses a use a template, which is a private member of class A.

I tried friend declaration but the template is still private within the context.

How to allow B to use a private template of A?

Test (also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cclass+T%3E%0Aclass+A+%7B%0Aprivate:%0A++++template%3Ctypename+R%3E+using+V+%3D+std::vector%3CR%3E%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+class+Prev%3E%0Aclass+B+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++friend+Prev%3B%0A++++typename+Prev::template+V%3CT%3E+v_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++B%3Cint,+A%3Cint%3E%3E+b%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.154046997389045,l:'4',m:71.89249720044792,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3+',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',m:48.99103139013454,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+5.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:51.00896860986548,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.84595300261096,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class A {
private:
    template<typename R> using V = std::vector<R>;
};

template <typename T, class Prev>
class B {
public:
    friend Prev;
    typename Prev::template V<T> v_;
};

int main() {
    B<int, A<int>> b;
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation Error:

```
error: ‘template<class R> using V 
       = std::vector<R, std::allocator<_CharT> >’ 
is private within this context
     typename Prev::template V<T> v_;
                                  ^~
```

Comment: `friend Prev;` makes `Prev` a friend of `B`. Not the other way round. The friendship has to be granted by `A`.

Comment: Thanks. Will make that one public. Need coffee ... Ok, actually there is a better fix. Nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

Fix (also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+class+Prev%3E+class+B%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cclass+T%3E%0Aclass+A+%7B%0A++++template+%3Ctypename+T2,+class+Prev%3E+%0A++++friend+class+B%3B%0Aprivate:%0A++++template%3Ctypename+R%3E+using+V+%3D+std::vector%3CR%3E%3B%0A%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+class+Prev%3E%0Aclass+B+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++typename+Prev::template+V%3CT%3E+v_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++B%3Cint,+A%3Cint%3E%3E+b%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.154046997389045,l:'4',m:71.89249720044792,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3+',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',m:48.99103139013454,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+5.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:51.00896860986548,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.84595300261096,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, class Prev> class B;

template <class T>
class A {
    template <typename T2, class Prev> 
    friend class B;
private:
    template<typename R> using V = std::vector<R>;

};

template <typename T, class Prev>
class B {
public:
    typename Prev::template V<T> v_;
};

int main() {
    B<int, A<int>> b;
    return 0;
}
```